# Generic DateTime List Comparison in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Generic DateTime List

```
List<DateTime> **PreviousDates** = //Some List of Dates
```

Now i want to Get all the Dates in the **PreviousDates** List whose Month and Year equals the GivenDate's Month & Year. no matter what the Day & Time are...

I Tried using List.Contains() method, but it checks all Parts of the Date, i want to check only Month&Year..

Help Me!

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `DateTime` values for the start and end of the interval:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(GivenDate.Year, GivenDate.Month, 1);
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(1);
```

Now you can easily select the items that is inside the interval:

```
List<DateTime> inside =
  PreviousDates
  .Where(d => d >= start && d < end)
  .ToList();
```

(You could of course compare the `GivenDate.Year` and `GivenDate.Month` values to `d.Year` and `d.Month` in the `Where`, but that's a more complex and less efficient condition.)

Comment: I think this is harder to understand as it doesn't explicitly state its purpose. Also, a tiny error, it should be AddMonth**s** .

Comment: @Joey: Thanks, corrected the error. I see how you can think of this as slightly more complicated than needed, but it's much more flexible. If you want to get the dates spanning two or three months instead, it's extremely easy with this code, but it gets much more complicated if you compare the year and month values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method. It will filter the list, and you can compare the Year and Month to the current date.

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var filteredDates = previousDates.Where(
    d => d.Year == currentDate.Year && d.Month == currentDate.Month);
```

Comment: Not *need*. There are plenty of other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to return an IEnumerable

```
PreviousDates.Where(d => d.Month == month && d.Year == year);
```

Comment: Missing an end bracket and semi-colon

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
DateTime criteria = DateTime.Today;
List<DateTime> filtered = previousDates.Where(dt => dt.Month == criteria.Month && dt.Year == criteria.Year).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't use `DateTime.Today` directly in the query. It can change halfway through the query, giving you a really weird result. Store it in a variable, and use the variable in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
previousDates.Where(d => d.Month == refDate.Month && d.Year == refDate.Year);
```